# Without using Greasemonkey is there a way to surf Pintrest without the annoying login/sign-up pop-ups with Adblock/Ublock?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, rules, adblock, ublock

I just want to browse Pintrest, not create yet another umpteenth account just so I can browse.

Is there a rule to remove the modal pop-ups in Pintrest in Adblock/Ublock without resorting to scripts with Greasemonkey?

I know Greasemonkey has it, bit I don't want to have yet another extension running.

Comment: I just tried blocking it from Firefox, but it doesn't work because page inspection shows that the whole page content is wrapped into that authentication div.

Answer (score 1):

You could try whether the following are sufficient for you:

```
pinterest.com##.Modal
pinterest.com##.Module.Nags
```

Otherwise you can use Adblock Plus' "Block element" feature. Other ad blockers should also have similar functionality to manually hide elements.